# Localhost 404 not found after modifying vhosts of LAMP stack

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I came across a weird situation. My localhost in Ubuntu LAMP installation gives 404 error, when I access `http://localhost/`.

All the files are in `/var/www/` folder. I can use phpmyadmin access which is placed in `/usr/shr/` folder. It was working fine earlier. It started happening after I was playing with vhosts. I reverted back all the things, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: there is probably something wrong with your configuration then. it's kind of hard to guess what without seeing. btw, this should probably be either on stackoverflow or serverfault, not on superuser.

Comment: Thanks eis for a reply, am the new user so didn't know where to post.I will recheck my config

Comment: @eis Please do not tell users to go ask somewhere else. This will lead to cross-posting which is not allowed. If you think a question is off topic and should be migrated, `flag` it for moderator attention, you don't have to tell the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Dushyant, your question is on-topic here. You don't have to post it on Stack Overflow because you don't face a programming issue and neither on Server Fault because you don't seem to be a server administrator in the professional environment. You might want to post your apache configuration though, we're missing a bit of information here.

Comment: Solved. I solved it by adding virtual host entry of localhost in httpd.conf. Thanks for support

Comment: Would be great if you could answer your own question with the added host here.